# Jest test functions on select statements in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am new to testing in jest and I was wondering if I could receive some clarity on a matter I am having difficulty understanding.

```
const getSelectField = () =>
  <SelectField
    name={name}
    id={id}
    aria-label="test"
    value={value}
    options={options} />;

describe('Select Field', () => {
  it('Renders SelectField', () => {
    const selectField = render(getSelectField());
    expect(selectField).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('Renders select field option', () => {
    render(getSelectField());
    expect(screen.findByRole('combobox'));
  });
```

I want to essentially be able to test the combobox(or select statement) and test the statements within but I really am just struggling to understand why I'm getting the errors I'm getting when it comes to the linting stage.

```
  29:5   error  Expect must have a corresponding matcher call             jest/valid-expect
  29:19  error  promise returned from `findByRole` query must be handled  testing-library/await-async-query

✖ 2 problems (2 errors, 0 warnings)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a matcher call after the last expect.

```
it('Renders select field option', () => {
    render(getSelectField());
    const comboBox = screen.findByRole('combobox');
    expect(comboBox).toBeInDocument();
  });
```

The screen.findByRole return a promise with a HTMLElement. which you dont handle.

Maybe try

```
screen.getByRole('combobox');
```